# Shanghai layover at night - shopping

Tags: layovers, shopping, shanghai

We have a 15 hour layover, over night, in Shanghai, where we would like to do some shopping (various stuff, like these huge markets they usually have in China with lots of small stores where you have to haggle). The problem is that the times are not optimal, we arrive at 19:30, and the next day we leave at 10:30, and I am not sure how late stores are open. If it changes anything, we will arrive on a Sunday evening.

The question is thus, what markets are there and where should we go for shopping, considering the limited time? It does not necessarily have to be in the vicinity of the airport, but we would probably take a hotel close to the shopping area. Our constraints are thus two; we need to be able to make it there in time before they close, and we need to be able to make it back to the airport the next morning

Comment: That looks like four valuable questions to me if separated...

Comment: For taxis, it’s imperative you have every address you want to go to written in Chinese, including your hotel, unless you speak mandarin of course.

Comment: @B.Liu sure, there are four questions in one, but I think that they are closely related enough to not need be separated. I also tried to make title and tags clear such that people can easily find the question if they search for similar things.

Comment: Japanese citizens can visit China without a visa for <= 15 days.

Comment: @bjorn They're not closely related at all. There's one about visas, one about shopping, one about taxis and one about pandas. They're completely separate.

Comment: @DavidRicherby okay, I have edited the question to put the focus on the main one which was about shopping.

Comment: @bjorn Thanks -- I've voted to reopen (I think it takes three votes). Do feel free to ask your other questions, too, in their own posts.

Answer (score 3):

Japanese citizens are among the few people who can visit China without requiring a visa. Japanese citizens can visit for tourism or business purposes without a visa for up to 15 days, so you're all set. You do not even need to use TWoV if you hold Japanese passports.

Pandas: no, I'm afraid not. Pandas aren't that common at all in China, and few zoos actually have pandas, and I am quite sure there's max 1 zoo per city. You'd have a better time if you save it until you return to Japan, acutally :-)

Taxis are fine as long as you can communicate with the driver. Subway is also fine, but crowded.